# Where is the Oracle java jdk keystore located?

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

Installed Oracle Java with the webupd8 ppa and need to tweak some policy settings (access to clipboard specifically)

webUpd8 plug: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html

(these guys have done alot for the Ubuntu community)

Previously it was under `/etc/java-6-oracle`

Google doesn't have any answers on this one -- any ideas?

Comment: This question was edited and so it no longer resembles my answer.  Jorqe?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The keystore is :  jre/lib/security/cacerts .   You can list its contents by:

```
keytool -list -keystore java.home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -v
```

To find JAVA_HOME, issue this command:

```
sudo apt-get install galternatives
```

And then run that program.

But, it sound to me like you dont need to alter the keystore.  What you need to do is edit the .policy file.   It's easy to find at:

```
java.home/jre/lib/security/java.policy
```

Of course, if you still cant find it then it is easy to derive with this command:

```
sudo find / -name "java"
```